# Sphinx "exception: No module named" error persists after autodoc_mock_imports is used

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am adding rst files to an existing repository using Sphinx v6.1.3 with `sphinx.ext.autodoc` extension.

when running `make html` the new rst file causes an error:

```
Extension error (sphinx_automodapi.automodsumm):
Handler <function process_automodsumm_generation at 0x7fedb8d30430> for event 'builder-inited' threw an exception (exception: No module named 'pandas')
make: *** [html] Error 2
```

(`pandas` is one import issue I'm having, but also having the issue with another import that I can't install in the environment, so using `pandas` for the sake of this question)

[Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports) offers the solution to use

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ["pandas"]
```

which I added to config.py

I then re-ran

```
$ make html
```

but the error persisted.

My folder structure is:

```
project_folder
└──doc
   ├── build
   ├── make.bat
   ├── Makefile
   └── source
      ├── conf.py
      ├── index.rst
      ├── _static
      └── problem
          └── index.rst
└──src
   └──project
      └──problem
         ├──__init__.py
         └──problem.py
```

my skimmed down root file (`project_folder/doc/source/index.rst`) is:

```
Project Documentation
===============================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   problem/index
   
Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

my skimmed down `conf.py`
(I went heavy on sys.path seeing if that would help)

```
# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../.."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../src"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../src/project"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../src/project/problem"))

autodoc_mock_imports = ['pandas']


extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.imgmath',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx_automodapi.automodapi'
]

templates_path = ['_templates']

exclude_patterns = ['project']

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
pygments_style = 'sphinx'


default_role = 'py:obj'
```

Finally, specific rst file (`project_folder/doc/source/problem/index.rst`) is:

```
Problem
=======

This package contains modules for Problem

Reference/API
-------------
.. module:: Project.problem

.. automodapi:: project.problem.problem
   :no-inheritance-diagram:
```

I appreciate any input!

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/astropy/sphinx-automodapi/issues/148

Comment: Are there any more hints about the error? From my experience, syntax error in python script may also result in similar error. The syntax error I made was that use module os while forgotten to import it first. Is it possible that you forget to import pandas before use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `make clean` first before running `make html` again to clear the existing `build` directory.